# Where can I find the org.mortbay classes for jetty-hightide?

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to follow these [Jetty/Howto/Spring instructions](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Spring). They say that you have to get a jetty-spring module which is in a jetty-hightide bundle at Codehaus.  I've downloaded 2 jetty-hightide-7.5 zips from there and neither of them contain any org.mortbay... packages. Is there another place I can get them?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt those were bundled in the hightide distro (which itself is being done away with in jetty 9 releases).

http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-spring/

You can find the binaries and source for each release here though.

Also, for jetty 9 that module has moved to Eclipse and can be found here:

http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-spring/

[edit] updated the docs for jetty-9 here:

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/frameworks.html#framework-jetty-spring